# Using Ubuntu Python packages and ImportError: No module named

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, module, installation

How to install Ubuntu's packaged modules instead of using `pip`?

All Python packages tell us to do the packages installation via `pip`, but Ubuntu has its own packaging system. I'd rather stick to using the system default packaging system instead of cooking my own using `pip`, but is that a good idea?

Searching for "`ImportError: No module named`" you'll get all kinds of such error for all kinds of different Python modules. I'm wondering if there is a general solution to use Ubuntu system default packaging system instead.

Specifically, I installed `python-jsonpath-rw` with

`sudo apt-get install python-jsonpath-rw`

but when I tried to do

`import sys, json, jsonpath`

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./pyjsonpath", line 2, in <module>
    import sys, json, jsonpath
ImportError: No module named jsonpath
```

I then searched, and found
http://blog.ingensol.pl/2015/03/need-to-make-quick-json-fixes-jsonpath.html

and followed all its commands,

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-jsonpath-rw
$ sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
$ sudo easy_install -U jsonpath
```

but am still getting the exact same errors as before.

Please help. Thx.

```
$ apt-cache policy python-jsonpath-rw
python-jsonpath-rw:
  Installed: 1.4.0-2
  Candidate: 1.4.0-2
  Version table:
 *** 1.4.0-2 500
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

$ dpkg -L python-jsonpath-rw
/.
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/python2-jsonpath
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jsonpath_rw
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jsonpath_rw/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jsonpath_rw/bin
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jsonpath_rw/bin/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jsonpath_rw/bin/jsonpath.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jsonpath_rw/jsonpath.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jsonpath_rw/lexer.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jsonpath_rw/parser.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jsonpath_rw-1.4.0.egg-info
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jsonpath_rw-1.4.0.egg-info/PKG-INFO
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jsonpath_rw-1.4.0.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jsonpath_rw-1.4.0.egg-info/entry_points.txt
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jsonpath_rw-1.4.0.egg-info/requires.txt
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jsonpath_rw-1.4.0.egg-info/top_level.txt
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/python-jsonpath-rw
/usr/share/doc/python-jsonpath-rw/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/python-jsonpath-rw/copyright

$ python -c "import sys, pprint; pprint.pprint(sys.path)"
['',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jsonpath-0.75-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
```

Comment: The first thing I'd suspect is that Ubuntu hasn't installed it to a directory in your PYTHONPATH. Do you have a '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages' directory? That's a semi-standard one it may have been installed to. But Ubuntu might do things differently.

Comment: Appears so. I don't have the `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages` directory. So after so many years, the Ubuntu Python packaging is still a joke? Shall I remove the Ubuntu package and do it `pip` way? Thanks @A.L.Flanagan. Oh, update, apparently `python-jsonpath-rw` is installed under `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`. OP updated.

Comment: @xpt It's a bit messy I find it unpredictable how `apt` installs the Python package. Maybe using `find` to look for names that contain `jsonpath` to see where they were installed?

Comment: The import is a typo, you want `from jsonpath_rw import jsonpath`